# How to restore deleted appointment

Tags: c#, restore, exchangewebservices, appointment

How to restore deleted appointment using EWS 2.0?
I think i could search for it in the WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsDeletions folder. But all i have is ItemId. And sadly I cant use it in SearchFilter...

What is the best way?

my try:

```
    ItemView view = new ItemView(10);

SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.Id, itemChange.ItemId);

var findResults = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsDeletions, searchFilter, view);

List<ItemId> ids = null;
foreach (var findResult in findResults)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(findResult.Id.ToString());
    ids.Add(findResult.Id);
}
exchangeService.MoveItems(ids, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
```

an error occurs:

> {"Values of type 'ItemId' can't be used as comparison values in search filters."}

Answer (score 1):

Set your WellKnownFolderName to DeletedItems when you are searching for the appointments. And you should set up your search filter to only return appointments since the DeletedItems folder can hold more than just the appointments you are looking for. Here is an example that should work for you.

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
// Only look for appointments
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Appointment");
// Look for items in the DeletedItems folder
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems, searchFilter, view);
// Move each of the deleted items back to the calendar
List<ItemId> ItemsToMove = new List<ItemId>();
foreach (Item item in results)
{
    ItemsToMove.Add(item.Id);
}
service.MoveItems(ItemsToMove, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
```