# How to access past modified calendar and contact items in outlook in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

I'd like to know how to access past modified calendar and contact items (include deleted items) in outlook (2010) in C#. I think they are stored somewhere in .pst file as they can be accessed in Undo action. I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 14.

Comment: Should be an easy Google to solve: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379041/how-to-restore-deleted-appointment

Comment: Why do you downvote without understanding fully this post? Your post does not solve the problem because it is for outlook 2013 and I am using 2010. I know to how to read item from outlook calendar and contact. But I need to access the past modified calendar and contact items as in Undo action. It is not trivial at all. For example, if item is deleted, it won't be in the list returned by myCalendar.Items.Restrict(filter). But I believe there should be a way to do it. The reason I need that is I try to write a program to sync calendars and contacts among different email accounts.

Comment: The correct approach may be to share a group/team calendar rather than try and sync multiple. Inviting people to meetings is the best way to make sure appointments are synchronized across people (email addresses). This post deals with restoring deleted appointments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379041/how-to-restore-deleted-appointment

Comment: What I need is to sync outlook calendar (under MyCalendar) with a calendar in email account also in MyCalendar. The calendar in email account (added by outlook email connector) is recently added by microsoft. After the change, I can't sync outlook calendar under MyCalendar with iphone in iTune. It looks like iTune only syncs calendar in email account and won't sync with  outlook calendar under MyCalendar.

Comment: Continue from last comment:  If I remove the email account, then it works for there is only one calendar under MyCalendar,  But I like to read email in outlook.This is annoying and the best solution is to write a program to sync calendars and contacts between calendar in email account  and outlook so that it will sync with iphone again. I think share a group/team  is not what I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379041/how-to-restore-deleted-appointment doesn't solve the my problem because I don't use EWS 2.0. Also I need to find the past modified items by time sequence (not only the deleted item, but also modified ones). I believe there should be a way to do it because you can undo the modification and deletion.

Comment: Now what you describe sounds like an iTunes change / bug that prevents you from working the way you want to. Writing your own sync software sounds excessive and will likely be brittle to future changes in Itunes/MyCalendar. I'd look for an alternative way of working or an app/product that does this already.

Comment: You are right. It is only temporary fix and I don't any other better way. Now I can't sync calendars and contacts with iphone, which is devastating. I think Microsoft intend to discourage people from hotmail and outlook email connector. That is why they made the change recently and can no longer sync with iphone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98895/discussion-between-murray-foxcroft-and-user585440).